# Kafka server goes down when there is no data flowing through the queue

Tags: apache-kafka

Recently there was no data flow through kafka server (no data produce so no data consume), turns out there is some limitations on kafka server is like when there is no data flow in kafka for specific period of time then it would down the kafka server.

I don't want like that since my data producing is not that consistence.

I want kafka server to be alive till I turn it down manually.

Can anyone help?

Comment: Where do you run it? How did you come to the conclusion there it turns off due to the fact there is no data flow? please elaborate

Comment: @NoamLevy
It is configured in my java service. Initially it is working fine because that time service is producing and consuming data at regular interval like for each 10-15 mins I will get a new data but now the data flow is like after 7-8 hrs and I haven't change any configuration or anything in kafka. 
So again restarted the kafka server then again same thing happens after some time.
So I have googled it, so it seems to be because of the limitation which kafka has. 
May be we can change the configuration or anything or may be I am wrong also.

Comment: No, Kafka has no such limitation. I've personally ran idle Kafka servers with uptime of days. Please edit your question to include all necessary versions, server configs and commands you're using to run the server. It shouldn't be embedded into another Java service.. Even if it does shut down for an error, you need to provide the server logs